# Java: my distrib differs from IDE debugging

Tags: java, utf-8, localization, ide

When I read from text file (UTF-8) by NetBeans IDE it reads both English and Russian letters correctly, but when I build distrib, run it and read the same file it doesn't recognize Russian letters(i guess it will happen with any language other than English).

What am I missing?

[image] [dead link to https://img607.imageshack.us/img607/1558/javabug.jpg ]

update:
How I read text file(I excluded all redundant for the case code):

```
bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String tempString;
tempString = bReader.readLine();
if ((tempString.length() >= 1) && (tempString.substring(0, 1).equals(""))) {
    tempString = tempString.substring(1);
}
//^^^ Former excludes UTF-8 Character at the beginning of a file
//it is actually placed in "", but it can't be seen here
while (tempString != null) {
    tempString = bReader.readLine();
}
```

So nothing really fancy here

What sir qrtt1 suggested in the comments below actually works, that is

> try add encoding configuration to vm: java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 your_main_class

Now I wonder how I can change my program without explicitly adding this parameters

Comment: Please post a code how exactly do you read a text file. It seems that you use default settings somewhere and they differ between your development and run time environments.

Comment: See the first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569419/java-strings-breaking-file-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add encoding configuration to vm:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 your_main_class
```

Usually java programs have tiny scripts that start them (`.bat` on windows, or shell scripts on *n?x), so that would be a great place to put options to java.

Comment: What kind of evil sorcery is that? It helped!
Is there anyway to "permanently" attach this setting to my program?
(Sorry for newbie question)